# Why did Reya choose this method to try to kill Adriel?

Tags: warrior-nun

In Season 2 of *Warrior Nun*, the extradimensional supernatural being Reya, who is more or less implied to be the inspiration for the Abrahamic God and claimed by Michael to be all-knowing, sent Michael back from her and Adriel's realm with a divinium bomb inside his body, to be activated by the Halo in order to kill Adriel.

When Ava activates the divinium bomb in Michael's body, it fails to kill Adriel, with him smugly reiterating that he cannot be killed while in the mortal realm. To add some further confusion, Adriel is apparently ultimately killed by a bunch of tarrasque demons that Ava summons by using the Halo as a lure, apparently suggesting that Adriel *can* be killed on Earth by things from his own world.

However, all-knowing or not, Reya certainly possesses great knowledge and is either the same type of being as Adriel or even his creator. If Adriel knows that divinium cannot kill him on Earth, she almost certainly must. Further, the tarrasques work for Reya (according to Adriel and as seen by her dismissing them) and are explicitly hunting down Adriel, and the Halo used to be hers, so it seems strange that she did not suggest that Ava summon her tarrasques to kill Adriel, which worked quite quickly and cleanly, instead of a bomb which she must have known would barely slow him down.

As such, why did Reya decide to attempt to kill Adriel using a divinium bomb? Did she have some larger plan in mind?

Comment: Who says calling tarasks wasn't a part of plan all the time, if he doesn't suffer enough damage? We don't really know. He clearly *is* wrong with this impossible to be killed thing. If the bomb itself could been enough is hard to tell. He was pretty far from the blast, and  his regeneration clearly had limits if he got destroyed later.